# Problematic conversion from unsigned_int to size_t

Tags: c++, size-t

First off, I am a c++ newbie. Excuse me if this question sounds stupid.

I am having a problem with the conversion from unsigned_int to size_t as shown in the VS compiler. Following are the lines of code that causes the compiler to complain.

```
size_t findNextAlphaNumericPosition(string &str)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(str[i])) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

It complains when it runs to this line:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
```

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated. It stops VS from compiling.

Comment: Ah, recovering Java programmer? Please consult a [library reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) when you have trouble remembering or knowing what a certain library interface looks like.

Comment: For future reference, you might want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). One point in the checklist is "If your code doesn't compile, have you included the exact compiler error?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) member of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a *function*, so you must call it:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
//            Note function call ^^
```